# Discord bot dont kick yourself or the bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I have the following commands:

````
@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def kick(ctx, member:discord.Member = None, *, reason="You smell bozo."):
    if(member == None):
        await ctx.reply("*Check your arguments!*\n```/kick @MEMBER REASON(optional)```")
    else:
        await member.kick(reason=reason)

@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def ban(ctx, member:discord.Member = None, *, reason="Bye Bye! :D."):
    if(member == None):
        await ctx.reply("*Check your arguments!*\n```/kick @MEMBER REASON(optional)```")
    else:
        await member.ban(reason=reason)
````

But how do i get it so I cant accidently kick myself or the bot itself?
Do i need to do like member=my_id? Completely new to making discord bots, hope someone can help.

Comment: if you are the server owner then you can't be kicked by anyone, and the bot can't kick itself from the server too

Comment: Compare the ID of the bot/the owner of the bot with the `member` one is trying to kick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider adding a check like this and add something like a message before returning:

```
if ctx.author.id in (member.id, self.bot.user.id):
    await return ctx.send("<message>")
```

Also, you should consider changing from `discord.Member` to `discord.User` for bans because `Member` is limited to only the ones who are still in the guild and pair it with a check like this to fetch the user if they're not in the guild:

```
if not isinstance(user, discord.Member):
    user = await self.bot.fetch_user(user)
```